# Why Blazor style isolation not working with routing?

Tags: c#, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-css-isolation

When a component is opened by navigating to its route, style isolation does not work, the styles are not applied, but if you add this component to another, then the styles work. I can’t understand if this is a feature of the framework or my mistake

Answer (score 0):

When a component is opened by navigating to its route, it's already a component within another component, so it will work exactly the same as your second case.  So I think the answer is "my mistake".

As you've provided no code, here's a very simple demo page showing it working in a routed component.

##### Test.razor

```html
@page "/"
<h3 class="makemered">Test</h3>
@code {
}
```

##### Test.razor.css

```css
.makemered {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

[image]